# JavaScript music volume changer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so I'm not to knwoledgeable on JavaScript so wouldn't know how to do this. Also from my searching I could only find how to use JavaScript to change the html audio tag volume, but that isn't what I want.

I want to be able to change the volume of this script below. I don't want an actual slider on the page, literally a variable I can change the value for in the script. (This code isn't mine, I found it and it works well for what I need).

```
var collection=[];
var loadedIndex=0;

function init(audios) {
  for(var i=0;i<audios.length;i++) {
    var audio = new Audio(audios[i]);
    collection.push(audio);
    buffer(audio);
  }
}

function buffer(audio) {
  if(audio.readyState==4)return loaded();
  setTimeout(function(){buffer(audio)},100);
}

function loaded() {
  loadedIndex++;
  if(collection.length==loadedIndex)playLooped();
}

function playLooped() {
  var audio=Math.floor(Math.random() * (collection.length));
  audio=collection[audio];
  audio.play();
  setTimeout(playLooped,audio.duration*1000);
}

init([
  'songs/1.ogg',
  'songs/2.ogg',
]);
```

The script basically picks one of the two songs at random and then plays it, it's just way to loud and I need some sort of volume adjustment. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> HTMLMediaElement.volume
>       A double indicating the audio volume, from 0.0 (silent) to 1.0 (loudest).

Set `audio.volume` to change the volume.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/volume